# При асинхронном шифровании проблема с русскими символами

Tags: java, android

Код такой:

```
public String encryptRSAToString(String text, String strPublicKey) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    String strEncryInfoData="";
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(strPublicKey.trim().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
        Key publicKey = keyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        strEncryInfoData = new String(Base64.encode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return strEncryInfoData.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
}

public String decryptStrToRSA(String text, String strPrivateKey) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    String strEncryInfoData="";
    //readKey(privateKey);
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(strPrivateKey.trim().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
        //KeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(strPrivateKey.trim().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        Key privateKey = keyFac.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        //cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT));
        strEncryInfoData = new String(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return strEncryInfoData.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
}
```

Если латинские символы использовать, то все Ок!

Comment: А вы уверены что ваши символы находятся в списке UTF-8 кодирования? Проверьте какой charset используется, вероятно нужно использовать UTF-16.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло :(

Comment: Текст для кодирования берется из EditText etInputText.getText().toString().trim(). Может нужно на этом этапе указать charset?

Comment: Java (and therefore Android) strings are not UTF-8, but UTF-16. The bytes displayed are Unicode code points. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787725/edittext-returns-enhanced-iso-8859-1-instead-utf-8-encoding-for-german-umlauts)

Comment: В ссылке есть инфа, что нельзя смешивать UTF-8 и UTF-16, но в моем примере нет смешивания.

Comment: В ответе там говорится что текст в Андроиде 16битный, а не 8, это я и имел в виду чтобы указывать UTF-16, а не UTF-8 для кодирования и раскодирования.

Comment: Во втором комментарии я написал, что пробовал UTF-16, но это не помогло. Более того, с UTF-16 даже простые цифры, обратно раскодируются с лишними символами.